# Get all tables in an Access database by ordinal position

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am coding in C# against an Access database...

I am able to get all of the tables in my access database with the following:

```
DataTable dataTbl;
DataView dvCols;
DataRowView drvCols;
```

...

```
dataTbl = m_connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, 
    new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
dvCols = new DataView(dataTbl);

for (int j = 0; j < dvCols.Count; j++)
{
    drvCols = dvCols[j];
    tableName = drvCols.Row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that this code gets the table names in alphabetical order. Now if I were reading the columns from particular table I could sort by ordinal position using

```
dvCols.Sort = "ORDINAL_POSITION";
```

However this is not possible with tables, there really is no ordinal position I guess. My tables have relationships, e.g. Table A has a one to many relationship to Table B which has a one to many relationship to  Table C, etc... So I need to get the table names in that order, e.g. A then B then C.

Is there any way to do this?
Do I need to somehow examine the primary and foreign keys and figure out this information myself?

Answer (score 1):

Ok..figured it out.
What I ended up doing was the following:

```
               dataTable_ForeignKeys = 
                m_connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys, null);

                //Check if a DataTable object is initialized
                if (dataTable_ForeignKeys != null)
                {
                    // iterate and get the names
                    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable_ForeignKeys.Rows)
                    {
                        tableName = row["PK_TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        tblNames.Add(tableName);
```

To get a list of the foreign key relationships. This returned the tables in the order I needed, i.e. 'parent' tables first. If a table is not the 'parent' of another table, i.e. it does not have a field that is the foreign key in another table then it will not be returned. I reconciled this by also getting all database table names as I did in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tables ordered according to their relationships, then, yes, you will have to implement that yourself (or find a third-party tool; I'm not aware of any).

Note that you will need some strategy for handling cycles in the relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented a solution that is working for me in my post below. What exactly do you mean by 'cycles in the relationships'? Could  you provide an example? I don't work with databases much.

Comment: The classic example is an employees table with a manager column that is a foreign key to the employees table.  In theory, of course, the cycle could also involve several tables (A related to B related to C related to A).